# Receiving messages as TcpClient

Tags: c#, tcp, client-server, tcpclient

I have been following this tutorial "http://tech.pro/tutorial/704/csharp-tutorial-simple-threaded-tcp-server" on setting up a mini server that can send and receive messages and have multiple clients connected.

Everything is working which is great.. but unfortunately one thing that is missing in this tutorial is how the client can set up a listener to listen to the server.

I have only this much:

```
public void SetupReceiver()
{
      TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient(this.Host, this.Port);
      NetworkStream networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();

      // What next! :( or is this already wrong...
}
```

As far as I can imagine.. I would need to connect to the server (As a TcpClient) and get the stream (Like above). And then wait for messages and do something with it. The reason I cannot just have the client receive a message back from the server immediately after sending one is because the client will send a message to the server, and then that message will be broadcast to all the clients that are connected. So each client needs to be "listening" for messages from the server.

Comment: The tutorial does show how to create the listener, where your comment is, they show a loop which will read incoming messages. (And return a byte array, which will need to be read into the correct formats depending on the data being sent)

Comment: Ah... I thought that was only for the server side, not the client side... Ok going to try and replicate that now :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The **TCPclient** class has the necessary resources to enable a connection, send and receive data to and from the server and the **TCPListener** class is essentially the server.

Following the general example provided in the msdn page for **TCPclient** and can also be used for **TCPListener** (of which my generalised explanation is based on!)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

The first part is to send data to the server:

```
// Translate the passed message into ASCII and store it as a Byte array.
Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);         

// Get a client stream for reading and writing. 
NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

// Send the message to the connected TcpServer. 
stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length); //(**This is to send data using the byte method**)
```

The following part is to receive data from the server:

```
// Buffer to store the response bytes.
data = new Byte[256];

// String to store the response ASCII representation.
String responseData = String.Empty;

// Read the first batch of the TcpServer response bytes.
Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length); //(**This receives the data using the byte method**)
responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes); //(**This converts it to string**)
```

The byte method can be replaced with **streamreader** and **streamwriter** once they have been linked to the **networkstream**

Hope this helps!!

**PS: If you would like a more versatile coding experience with networking classes in c#, i would personally recommend looking into using sockets as it is the main class from which the tcpclient and tcplistener are born.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer! And very sorry for my late reply. Could I just add a question to a question and ask where the "receive data from the server" code should go. How would the client be "waiting" for data to be received? The reason I ask is because the server is broadcasting the message to other clients so the reply won't only occur to the client that sent the original message

Comment: Ok, then you may have to create a method that would send the same message to each individual connection. Tcp is a one on one connection while as UDP for example (although less secure and less reliable if you want everything to get from point a to b) broadcasts messages much easier. To my knowledge there isnt a way to broadcast tcp wirhout cycling through each connection